# How to keep an image background image still?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I would like to keep an image fixed as a background while I scroll a semi-transparent box over it. However when I try an do this on a 4:3 ratio screen the image just cuts in half.

Here is my CSS:

```
.content {
    background-color: black;
    background-image:url('http://xurbia.tk/alpha/pictures/Croped%20Xurbiar%20Logo%20Mr.%20Isolation.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;        
}
```

Here is an example of what I would like to do:

http://s.codepen.io/shardros/debug/vOVWwp

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background on the `body` tag instead of `.content`, that will do it.

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    background-image:url('http://xurbia.tk/alpha/pictures/Croped%20Xurbiar%20Logo%20Mr.%20Isolation.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;        
}
```

**[Updated Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPemNm?editors=110)**

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a problem with your `background-size`, not keeping it still.

Try `background-size: contain` instead of `cover`.

Differences are here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size